# using laravel in a subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, shared-hosting

It seems to me that the idea behind laravel is that the public/ directory is where your DocumentRoot points to and that the app/, vendor/, bootstrap/ and build/ directories all live outside the web root. But what happens if you want the laravel project to live in a subdirectory.

ie. `http://www.domain.tld/` might be static HTML, `http://www.domain.tld/phpbb/` is phpBB and you wanted your laravel app to live at `http://www.domain.tld/app/`.

Should you just put the entire laravel folder in `http://www.domain.tld/app/` and redirect, via .htaccess, all requests to `http://www.domain.tld/app/public/`? That seems inelegant.

Maybe you could put laravel in `http://www.domain.tld/` and rename the /public/ directory to /app/ but that seems even more inelegant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The question is why you need it in subdirectory. So far I never need to put custom project into subdirectory. I use domain or subdomain if needed.

You could try with:

- renaming your public directory to the directory name you want to use
- put other directories into your root domain directory
- add .htaccess for those directories with `deny from all` (to block access from your root domain)
- edit paths in `bootstrap/paths.php`

I haven't tested it and I wouldn't probably even try to do that. Many frameworks are rather created to use them on separate domains or subdomains and not in directories so I would recommend you to rethink it.

Answer (score 0):

Use virtual hosts in your web engine (eg. apache, nginx, IIS, etc.) and point the document root for your alias to your laravel app.